# Samba сервер и таймер бездействия

Tags: linux, debian, samba

Имеется Samba сервер с Debian на борту. Включена стандартными средствами функция при бездействии 20 минут уходить в спящий режим.

Проблема в следующем: подключаюсь, запускаю просмотр фильма и через 20 мин. срабатывает таймер по бездействию.

Можно ли как-то настроить (где-нибудь), чтобы если идёт нагрузка по чтению с диска (или какой нибудь другой подходящий в моём случае параметр) отключался таймер бездействия. Ну а после того, как просмотр фильма закончился, он включался обратно.

Просто напросто выключить таймер такое себе решение, потому что придётся заходить на сервер и уводить его в спячку, да и не хочется чтобы он всю ночь работал в холостую.

Comment: у самбы нет хуков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по нагрузке сети сделать необходимую реакцию.
пример:

```
#!/bin/perl
#указать свой сетевой интерфейс
my $net="eth0";
#таймаут между замерами
my $timeout=1;

my $R1=`cat /sys/class/net/$net/statistics/rx_bytes`;
my $T1=`cat /sys/class/net/$net/statistics/tx_bytes`;

sleep $timeout;

my $R2=`cat /sys/class/net/$options{net}/statistics/rx_bytes`;
my $T2=`cat /sys/class/net/$options{net}/statistics/tx_bytes`;
#переводим в мб
my $TBPS=int(($T2 - $T1) / 1024 / 125);
my $RBPS=int(($R2 - $R1) / 1024 / 125);

#раскоментировать для отладки
#print "$net TX (upload): $TBPS kB/s | RX(download): $RBPS kB/s\n";

#проверяем скорость отдачи, подобрать вручную
if ($TBPS >= 5){
    system ("service stop timer");# - тут указываем команду для остановки таймера;
}else{
    system ("service start timer");# - тут указываем команду для запуска таймера

}
```

Скрипт можно запускать раз в несколько минут по крону